Oracle RCU Database Connection Details Connect String with Oracle Cloud Free trial DB not able to connect
I am encountering the error below. I tried both with jdbc:oracle:thin:@ and without it. I didn't understand what is the issue?
The error is:

Unable to connect to the DB. Check if DB connection details entered are correct.
IO Error: Undefined Error

Below is the connection string:
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description= (retry_count=5)(retry_delay=3)(address=(protocol=tcps)(port=1521)(host=adb.eu-frankfurt-1.oraclecloud.com))(connect_data=(service_name=j34453243241a2_u0u7bz6js8w0cvl3_XXX.adb.oraclecloud.com))(security=(ssl_server_dn_match=yes)))

I am trying to be able to connect. I can connect using wallet through SQL Developer to this DB.

This works for me
Extract wallet in some location, let's say we have extracted in   PATH_TO_WALLET .
And tns alias name is something odatabse_high
Then connect string should be
jdbc:oracle:thin:@odatabse_high?TNS_ADMIN=PATH_TO_WALLET
